# Number of subgroups of order $4$ and $8$ in a group of order $72$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, math-software, gap, computational-algebra

Let $G$ be a group of order $72$. I want to calculate the number of subgroups of order $4$ and $8$ with GAP. How can I do? thanks in advance.

Comment: I've seen that this and many other questions have answers which are upvoted but not accepted. If you're not completely satisfied with the answer, please use comments to ask further questions. Otherwise, please think about accepting the answer - there is a [help page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) with more details on this. Accepting an answer will also give $+2$ to your Math.SE reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of possible values:

```
gap> Set(AllSmallGroups(72),g->List([4,8],n->Number(AllSubgroups(g),h->Order(h)=n)));
[ [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 1, 9 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 7, 1 ], [ 7, 3 ], [ 9, 9 ], [ 15, 9 ],
  [ 19, 3 ], [ 19, 9 ], [ 27, 9 ], [ 51, 9 ], [ 55, 9 ] ]
```

For instance there are groups of order 72 that have 55 subgroups of order 4 and 9 subgroups of order 8.